# Have eclipse "quick diff" reference source on a per project basis?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I'm using Eclipse Indigo and was wondering if I can configure [Quick diff](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-cvs-quickdiff.htm), especially the *Reference source*, on a per project basis?

Not all of my projects use SVN or GIT, etc. and so I've to switch several times.

Comment: I am looking for this as well. Did you have any luck finding the solution? Maybe file a bug with them?

Comment: @billc.cn: no, haven't so far and just gave up searching.